# Converting two pandas columns in list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
         Open       min       max                Date
Loc
0    0.000329  0.000329  0.000000 2020-07-06 05:00:00
3    0.000337  0.000000  0.000337 2020-07-06 08:00:00
13   0.000330  0.000000  0.000330 2020-07-06 18:00:00
19   0.000320  0.000320  0.000000 2020-07-07 00:00:00
22   0.000328  0.000000  0.000328 2020-07-07 03:00:00
25   0.000320  0.000320  0.000000 2020-07-07 06:00:00
34   0.000330  0.000330  0.000000 2020-07-07 15:00:00
39   0.000351  0.000000  0.000351 2020-07-07 20:00:00
```

I need to convert the two columns `min` and `max` in a single list. That would be easy enough to do, the problem is that i need to have the elements ordered in a specific way, like this: [`min`, `max`, `min`, `max` ...], so they basically should be sorted in the same order they are on my pandas Dataframe. How can i do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
# df is the dataframe
list_ = df[['min', 'max']].stack().tolist()
```

list_ is the desired output you want.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Give me 10 minutes to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your specific question has already been answered. If case you would want the output as a list of lists (`[[min, max],[min, max],...]`), you can use list comprehension:

```
output = [[x,y] for x,y in zip(df['min'],df['max']]
```